# FB Warning incorrectly shuts down my script.

Tags: facebook, warnings, facebook-comments

I have a php/html script that is fully functional (has run for many months both within FB until recently and outside of FB) if not run within FB.  When run within FB I get the following warning if a second html form attempts to run after a first html form runs...

> **App Temporarily Unavailable
>   Runtime errors:**
>   cannot nest form within a form

Question #1: Can I turn off the FB Warning system? If so how?

Question #2: Why would FB Warn as shown above for a script as basic as the one below which is a paraphrasing example of my actual script.  The behavior when run within FB is that the first form is displayed and behaves as expected but the second form is not even displayed because FB cuts off execution and puts out the warning mentioned above.  As you can see, I'm not "nesting" forms. NOTE: The actual script runs fine if not run within FB and, therefore, not subject to FB's Warning code.

Code sample (Problem area only shown):

```
<?php
.
.
.
echo "
<form name='FBregister method='get' target='_self'>
<input type='submit' value='REGISTER' name='FBlogin' >
</form>

<form name='FBloginSubmit' method='get' target='_self'>
<input type='submit' value='LOGIN' name='FBlogin' >
</form>
.
.
.
?>
```

All help is appreciated.
Bob G.

Comment: The code example I tried to provide was truncated on the front end.  The example should start as follows...<!php  echo" <form name='FBRegister' method='get' target='_self'> <input type='submit' value='REGISTER' name='FBlogin'> </form> ...